# How do I get href links under a specific class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is an example of the type of block of HTML source code I'm targeting with BeautifulSoup

```
 <div class="fighter_list left">
                            <meta itemprop="image" content="/image_crop/44/44/_images/fighter/1406924569376_20140801011731_Picture17.JPG">
                            <img class="lazy" src="/image_crop/44/44/_images/fighter/1406924569376_20140801011731_Picture17.JPG" data-original="/image_crop/44/44/_images/fighter/1406924569376_20140801011731_Picture17.JPG" alt="Jason DeLucia" title="Jason DeLucia" />
                            <div class="fighter_result_data">
                                <a itemprop="url" href="/fighter/Jason-DeLucia-22"><span itemprop="name">Jason<br />DeLucia</span></a><br>
```

This is one of multiple blocks like this for each "fighter_list left" on the page.

I want to get all of the itemprop="url" href links that are in the "fighter_list left" class (i.e. /fighter/Jason-DeLucia-22)

When I try the below code I get nothing.

```
for link in html.find_all('a', class_="fighter_List left", itemprop="url"):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The closest I can get is getting every itemprop=url link on the page when I omit the class_= part.
But I only want the ones under the fighter_list left class.

This is the website https://www.sherdog.com/events/UFC-1-The-Beginning-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS selector for the task:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sherdog.com/events/UFC-1-The-Beginning-7"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select('.fighter_list.left [itemprop="url"]'):
    print(link["href"])
```

Prints:

```
/fighter/Jason-DeLucia-22
/fighter/Royce-Gracie-19
/fighter/Gerard-Gordeau-15
/fighter/Ken-Shamrock-4
/fighter/Royce-Gracie-19
/fighter/Kevin-Rosier-17
/fighter/Gerard-Gordeau-15
```